# I need my csv out put to use commas instead of semicolons so I can insert it into my sqlite DB

Tags: python, csv, nmap

Right now my nmap csv is putting semicolons in the file which I need to change to commas.

nmap scan

```
import first
import csv
import nmap
csvFilePath = "nmapscan1.csv"
ipAddress = first.ipAddress
port = first.port

#nmap scan using user input varibles
nm = nmap.PortScanner()

nm.scan(ipAddress,port)

csv = nm.csv()
print(csv)

#writing to csv file
with open(csvFilePath, "w") as csvFile:
    csvFile.write(csv)
#changes ; to , for database use
with open(r"nmapscan1.csv") as in_file, open(r"nmapscan.csv", 'w') as 
out_file:
    semicolonin = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=';')
    commaout = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in semicolonin:
        commaout.writerow(row)
```

error I get in Ubuntu terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second.py", line 23, in <module>
    semicolonin = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=';')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

Comment: `csv.read` instead of `csv.reader`

Answer (score 0):

Set a different name to `csv` on `csv = nm.csv()`. It is overwriting your `csv` on `import csv`.

**Edited***

This part:

```
csv_data = nm.csv()
print(csv_data)

#writing to csv file
with open(csvFilePath, "w") as csvFile:
    csvFile.write(csv_data)
```